# PowerShell: Looping through an .ini file

Tags: powershell, loops, if-statement, foreach, ini

I'm working on a PowerShell script that will do the following:

1. Use a function to grab the ini data and assign it to a hashtable (basically what Get-IniContent does, but I'm using one I found on this site).
2. Check the nested keys (not the sections, but the keys of each section) to see if the value "NoRequest" exists.
3. If a section contains a NoRequest key, and ONLY IF the NoRequest value is false, then I want to return the name of the section, the NoRequest key, and the key's value. For example, something like "Section [DataStuff] has a NoRequest value set to false." If a section doesn't contain a NoRequest key, or the value is set to true, then it can be skipped.

I believe I've accomplished the first two parts of this, but I'm unsure of how to proceed with the third step. Here's the code I have so far:

```
function Get-IniFile 
{  
    param(  
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string] $filePath  
    )  

    $anonymous = "NoSection"

    $ini = @{}  
    switch -regex -file $filePath  
    {  
        "^\[(.+)\]$" # Section  
        {  
            $section = $matches[1]  
            $ini[$section] = @{}  
            $CommentCount = 0  
        }  

        "^(;.*)$" # Comment  
        {  
            if (!($section))  
            {  
                $section = $anonymous  
                $ini[$section] = @{}  
            }  
            $value = $matches[1]  
            $CommentCount = $CommentCount + 1  
            $name = "Comment" + $CommentCount  
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value  
        }   

        "(.+?)\s*=\s*(.*)" # Key  
        {  
            if (!($section))  
            {  
                $section = $anonymous  
                $ini[$section] = @{}  
            }  
            $name,$value = $matches[1..2]  
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value  
        }  
    }  

    return $ini  
}  

$iniContents = Get-IniFile C:\testing.ini

    foreach ($key in $iniContents.Keys){
    if ($iniContents.$key.Contains("NoRequest")){
        if ($iniContents.$key.NoRequest -ne "true"){
        Write-Output $iniContents.$key.NoRequest
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the run the above code, it gives me the following expected output, since I know there are four instance of NoRequest in the INI and only one of them is set to false:

```
false
```

I believe I've solved the problem of finding the correct value(s) from the file, but I'm unsure of how to proceed with getting the correct output as mentioned in step 3 above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. This will output a string in the form you mentioned:

```
$key = "NoRequest" # They key you're looking for
$expected = "false" # The expected value
foreach ($section in $iniContents.Keys) {
    # check if key exists and is set to expected value
    if ($iniContents[$section].Contains($key) -and $iniContents[$section][$key] -eq $expected) {
        # output section-name, key-name and expected value
        "Section '$section' has a '$key' key set to '$expected'."
    }
}
```

Of course, since you said..

> If a section contains a NoRequest key, and ONLY IF the NoRequest value
>   is false, then I want to return the name of the section, the NoRequest
>   key, and the key's value.

.. the key-name and -value will always be the same in the output.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for! The "make output" section is a lot simpler than I would have expected, I was probably trying to make it more complex than necessary when trying to do it on my own.